# I wan to download the certificates from URL using Java code, No for say ignore certificate or do manual steps to download from browser and add keystor

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, rest-assured

[image]

During the development of a Java webservice client I ran into a problem. Authentication for the webservice is using a client certificate, a username and a password. The client certificate I received from the company behind the webservice is in .cer format.

I know we can do the above steps as shown in pic, but my question is tools like postman or soapUi automatically takes care of this steps. so, I want to implement the same in my java code.

Can some give me code to download .cer file using java code

Comment: Something like [THIS](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert)?

Answer (score 0):

I have built in the past an utility class which can do this. The usage is basically:

```
List<X509Certificate> certificates = CertificateUtils.getCertificatesFromExternalSource("https://github.com/");
```

The library is available here: [GitHub: SSLContext-kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart) You can add it to your maven project with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
    <artifactId>sslcontext-kickstart</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```